# A way to retain MPMoviePlayerController.view subviews?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there no way to enable MPMoviePlayerController's view to retain its subviews when entering fullscreen mode?

When you add subviews to the MPMoviePlayerController.view property when the video isn't playing full screen, all is good, the views display as expected. However, when you tap the fullscreen button, they disappear.

When leaving fullscreen mode they animate back in just fine, but if you're adding content relevant to the video using HTTPLiveStreaming it's not a great user experience losing it all when wanting full screen.

I've experimented with NSNotifications on MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification to add the views once more when entering full screen, but to no avail, they just don't appear.

The only other solution I can think of is faking full screen by rolling my own playback controls with new full screen button & method and also trying to override the full screen pinch gesture recognizer that exists with the MPMoviePlayerConroller.view

Unless there's something I've missed / a better idea?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The fullscreen-mode is **not** using `MPMoviePlayerController.view`.

Use this snippet to get the view you can add your subviews to when using `MPMoviePlayerController` in fullscreen-mode;

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window)
{
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
}
view = [[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Hey Till thanks for that info.

I tried out your code and indeed it works, however. I may go with my hack unless anyone has a better idea for a couple of reasons.

1. the subviews for no period of time are removed from the view i.e. during animation to/from fullscreen.
2. These views are dynamic and are fed in from ID3 information coming in from the HTTPLiveStream. So they have their own animation blocks they are running in and know when/how to animate themselves.

Thanks for your input though, may have been fine with that were it not so dynamic.